# Is it safe to use jTDS emulated XA transaction support with a single SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, jtds, jboss-eap-6, xa

I am currently using a jTDS driver to connect to a SQL Server database from a JBoss EAP 6 environment.

Dfeature communicating with three resources (1 SQL Server DB and 2 JMS servers) I am employing XA Transactions. jTDS documentation clearly states it does not support XA Transactions natively and instead offers XA emulation that may fail in certain conditions.

On the other hand, jTDS documentation tells this should be fine as long as it is the only resource manager. Does this mean it can be safely used in combination with two other XA JMS servers (no other DB involved)?